# Create class by merging function and object in one statement. Alternative way to define a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

What **irritates** me:

```
PersonClass = function(){
    console.log("Person created!")
}
PersonClass.prototype = {name:"John Doe"}
```

we have to put class name "PersonClass" at least **twice**, to declare class with properties.
What i've come to:

```
with(PersonClass = function(){
    console.log("Person created!")
})
{
    prototype = {name:"John Doe"}
}
```

It's pretty ugly, **but**! We don't have to excessively write PersonClass each time we want to define a class structure. My question is: did you know some other alternative, probably kinky ways to declare a class in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://classy.pocoo.org/, with it you can define clases like:

```
var Animal = Class.$extend({
   __init__ : function(name, age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
     this.health = 100;
},

die : function() {
   this.health = 0;
 },

eat : function(what) {
   this.health += 5;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
(PersonClass = function(){
    console.log("Person created!")
}).prototype = {name:"John Doe"}
```

But this isn't particularly good style. Normally, the way you declare objects depends on your framework. `$.extend`, `Class.create` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `with` and having to pay attention to all of its pitfalls, you could write a function that creates the class for you:

```
function createClass(options) {
  options.constructor.prototype = options.prototype;
  return options.constructor;  
}

PersonClass = createClass({
  constructor: function(){
    console.log("Person created!");
  },
  prototype : {name:"John Doe"}
});


var p = new PersonClass();
console.log(p.name);
```

Another interesting alternative is:

```
Function.prototype.addPrototype = function(prototype) {
  this.prototype = prototype;
  return this;
}

PersonClass2 = function() {  
    console.log("Person created!");
}.addPrototype({ name:"John Doe" });

var p2 = new PersonClass2();
console.log(p2.name);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AJItuJA/1/edit